# Why is swift's character comparison so slow?

Tags: performance, swift

I was writing some code in swift that involved a lot of comparing of characters in words and found it to be very slow.  When I checked Instruments, it said that about 33% of the cpu was being taken by infix == on two Characters, so I wrote this to test it:

```
import Foundation
let numTimes = 1000000

let charA: Character = "a";
let charB: Character = "b";
let stringA: String = "a";
let stringB: String = "b";
let nsStringA: NSString = "a";
let nsStringB: NSString = "b";

var start = NSDate();
for var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++ {
    charA == charB;
}
println("Swift Char Time: \(start.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1)")

start = NSDate();
for var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++ {
    stringA == stringB;
}
println("Swift String Time: \(start.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1)")

start = NSDate();
for var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++ {
    nsStringA == nsStringB;
}
println("NSString Time: \(start.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1)")
```

The result:
Swift Char Time: 2.94823098182678
Swift String Time: 0.413999974727631
NSString Time: 0.228329002857208

Does anyone know why this would be?

Answer (score 3):

I found your question very interesting, and I go deeper with the Swift Documentation, so here is my supposition :

`Character` type is a Unicode scalar (21-bit number), so when you test `charA == charB`, the CPU is comparing two Unicode scalar.

`String` is a collection of Unicode scalar, so when you test `stringA == stringB`, the CPU is comparing the hashcode of the collection, so it's more lighweight than a Unicode scalar.

And I found that in the [Swift doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) : "*Swift’s String type is bridged seamlessly to Foundation’s NSString class*", that can explain the time difference between `NSString` and `String` comparison.

I will update the answer to confirm, when I will have more time to go deeper.